# How to generate a token code iOS DeviceId using DeviceCheck.DCDevice Xamarin Forms C#

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin Forms and I need a Device Id from the iOS device.
This changes when the app is removed and reinstalled.
I need a constant Device Id for the device.

I have been informed that I can use DeviceCheck.DCDevice in Xamarin forms iOS.
This generates a token through Apple that identifies the device.
Has anyone a code example that I can follow to achieve this?
using DCDevice.GenerateToken...
C# iOS

Comment: Posting an answer soon but just so you know its xamarin.ios and not forms you will have to work on the dependency service later on

Answer (score 2):

> Use DeviceCheck.DCDevice in Xamarin forms iOS.

```
if (DCDevice.CurrentDevice.Supported)
   {
       DCDeviceGenerateTokenCompletionHandler handler = (NSData token, NSError error) =>
           {                    
                   // Upload token to App server
           };
       DCDevice.CurrentDevice.GenerateToken(handler);
   }
```

To use `DeviceCheck.DCDevice` in Xamarin.iOS, for my understanding, `DeviceCheck` doesn't give a Device ID like `IdentifierForVendor` or `UUId` that won't change and always represent that device. Be aware that `DeviceCheck` is only available above iOS 11.

*Your app uses the DeviceCheck APIs to generate an ephemeral token that identifies a device. Your associated server combines this token with an authentication key that you receive from Apple, and uses the result to request access to the per-device bits.*

I think the way to identify a device using `DeviceCheck.DCDevice` depending on your app's 
business logic.

You can read this article([devicecheck-tutorial](https://fluffy.es/devicecheck-tutorial/)) to better understand what DeviceCheck really doing and then achieve your requirements.

Here a also a sample in swift you can refer: [DeviceCheckSample](https://github.com/marinosoftware/DeviceCheckSample)

Apple document: [devicecheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck?language=objc)

> I am using Xamarin Forms and I need a Device Id from the iOS device. I
>   need a constant Device Id for the device.

There are several other options for you to choose:

1. Store your Device ID in `Keychain`, it might persist through App removal/reinstalls.
2. If you app have advertisement, you can use [Advertising Identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier?language=objc) to identify a device and send this data to server to check the device ID.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Xamarin.Forms, you will need to use DependencyService.

Here's how:

First declare an Interface in your Forms Project

```
public interface IDeviceInfo {
    string GetDeviceId ( ); //note that interface members are public by default
}
```

Then, in your iOS Project,

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (DeviceInfoiOS))]
    namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
    {
        public class DeviceInfoiOS : IDeviceInfo
        {
            public string GetDeviceId ()
            {
                return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.AsString();        
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
DependencyService.Get<IDeviceInfo>().GetDeviceId();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments Bruno.
The problem I am facing is that the DeviceId changes when the App is removed and reinstalled.  I need a concrete device Id of the hardware so I can add it to inventory. 
The code you have provided does not solve this problem.
It would be the same as calling CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id from my forms project would it not?

Comment: Yes that is the same as calling `CurrentId`